# How to stop duplication of post when making post from csv file import?

Tags: php

I already have a function,in that m geeting post tilte from csv file,,but its coming in a string,,how can i prevent insert post duplication

```
 var $defaults = array(
                'playername '    => null,
                'country'        => null,
                'post_type'      =>'player',
                 'year'           => null,
                'my_post_tags'   => null,
                'post_slug'      => null,
                'clubs'             => null

            );  



      function create_post($data, $options) {
 $opt_draft = isset($options['opt_draft']) ? $options['opt_draft'] : null;
 $opt_cat = isset($options['opt_cat']) ? $options['opt_cat'] : null;

                $data = array_merge($this->defaults, $data);
                $new_post = array(
                    'post_title'   => convert_chars($data['playername']),
                    'post_status'  => $opt_draft,
                    'post_type'    => 'player',
                    'post_name'    => $data['post_slug'],

                );
        $title = $data['playername'] ;

                $id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
       update_post_meta($id, 'club',    convert_chars($data['clubs']));
       update_post_meta($id, 'year', convert_chars($data['year']));
       update_post_meta($id, 'year', convert_chars($data['country']));
        return $id;

        }
```

Comment: make tight integrity in database using unique or primary key, then insert with error trapping ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if( null == get_page_by_title( convert_chars($data['clubs']), '','player' ) ) {
    $new_post = array(
                    'post_title'   => convert_chars($data['playername']),
                    'post_status'  => $opt_draft,
                    'post_type'    => 'player',
                    'post_name'    => $data['post_slug'],

                );
        $title = $data['playername'] ;

                $id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
       update_post_meta($id, 'club',    convert_chars($data['clubs']));
       update_post_meta($id, 'year', convert_chars($data['year']));
       update_post_meta($id, 'year', convert_chars($data['country']));
        return $id;
}
```

Comment: i have used  if( null == get_page_by_title( $data['playername'] ) ) thats why it was not working